# Session state SQLServer mode using Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g, session-state

Is it possible to use Oracle database? Web app is currently using Oracle and may not have access to SQL Server.

Thanks.

RO

Comment: No, that won't work. This session mode is **specifically** for Microsoft SQL Server - no other database system is supported. But there's nothing stopping you from [writing your own custom Session-State provider specifically for Oracle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you really want to ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of-the-box that's not possible. ASP.NET supports the following [session state providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

- In-Process - the session is stored into the memory of the web server
- State Server - the session is serialized and stored into the memory of a specific server running the ASP.NET session state service. This could be a different machine from the web server
- SQL Server - the session is serialized and persisted into a MS SQL Server database

The SQLServer sessionState mode uses, as it's names suggests, SQL Server. If you want to use Oracle you will have to write a custom session state provider by inheriting from the [`SessionStateStoreProviderBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) class and overriding all the methods.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible in fact Oracle provides library of asp.net providers including :
    Membership Provider
    Role Provider
    Site Map Provider
    Session State Provider
    Profile Provider
    Web Events Provider
    Web Parts Personalization Provider
    Cache Dependency Provider

You can find them here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-087367.html